# How to disable openfire from auto start after booting?

Tags: linux, configuration

I'm in such a trouble now

```
[root@jiaoyou ~]# cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 10 (Cambridge)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/sbin/chkconfig openfire off
```